# pywin32 is installed but the dependency package could not found it

Tags: python, path, pywin32, xlwings

OS：windows

ERROR info：

> xlwings.XlwingsError: Make sure to have "pywin32", a dependency of xlwings, installed.

I am using a company computer. Due to some restrictions, I installed Python by unzipping the zip file. Python is not added to the Windows system path. I run Python through git bash + IDE

```
Bash profile
export PYTHON_HOME=~/tools/python-3.10.11-embed-amd64
export PATH=$PYTHON_HOME:$PYTHON_HOME/Scripts:$PATH
```

I would appreciate any help

Things I checked and try

```
$ pip show pywin32
Name: pywin32
Version: 306
Summary: Python for Window Extensions
Home-page: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32
Author: Mark Hammond (et al)
Author-email: mhammond@skippinet.com.au
License: PSF
Location: c:\users\patrick.pc.chen\tools\python-3.10.11-embed-amd64\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: xlwings
```

run postinstall

```
$ python Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install
Parsed arguments are: Namespace(install=True, remove=False, wait=None, silent=False, quiet=False, destination='**\python-3.10.11-embed-amd64\\Lib\\site-packages')
Copied pythoncom310.dll to **\python-3.10.11-embed-amd64\pythoncom310.dll
Copied pywintypes310.dll to **\python-3.10.11-embed-amd64\pywintypes310.dll
You do not have the permissions to install COM objects.
The sample COM objects were not registered.
-> Software\Python\PythonCore\3.10\Help[None]=None
-> Software\Python\PythonCore\3.10\Help\Pythonwin Reference[None]='**\python-3.10.11-embed-amd64\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyWin32.chm'
Registered help file
Pythonwin has been registered in context menu
Can't install shortcuts - '**\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Python 3.10' is not a folder
The pywin32 extensions were successfully installed.
```